# Photoshop script arrange selected layers in grid

Tags: javascript, photoshop

It sounds super simple, I just want to arrange all my selected layers in a simple grid. This is what I whipped up:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var hasLayers = doc.activeLayer.layers.length;

 

if (hasLayers > 0) {

    var selectedLayers = doc.activeLayer.layers;

 

    var cols = 11;

    var rows = 11;

    var xOffset = 512;

    var yoffset = 512;

 

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedLayers.length; i++){

        var layer = selectedLayers[i];

 

        var row = Math.floor(i / rows);

        var col = i % cols;

 

        var newX = col * xOffset;

        var newY = row * yoffset;

 

        layer.translate(newX, newY);

    }

 

    doc.activeLayer = doc.activeLayer;

    doc.activeLayer = doc.backgroundLayer;

 

    alert("It worked!");

} else {

    alert("Didnt work");

}
```

I just get:

```
Error 21: undefined is not an object. Line: 2 -> var hasLayers = doc.activeLayer.layers.length;
```

How can I make it work?

I tried removing the `if` statement altogether but it still didn't work.

Comment: Welcome! Either `var doc = app.activeDocument;` doesn't represent an Object or `layers` in your `var hasLayers = doc.activeLayer.layers.length;` isn't an Object to get `.length`. console.log your `doc` to see if that's even an Object.

Comment: Turns out doc.activeLayers.layers doesnt work, it's supposed to be doc.layers. Thank you!